# I can't delete the last blank page in word with c#

Tags: c#

The d.docx document only a table, across four pages, the last page is a blank page, there is no content.
However, if the mouse cursor is located at the top of the blank page, it will become recognized to the state of the form, then right-click the mouse, open source to see the "Delete Cells" option, if you click to delete the cell, the dialog box will pop up, and then choose to delete the line, so three times in a row.
This is the third consecutive time, the blank page will disappear. This should be the form of overflow, resulting in a blank page!

I tried, Open XML, DocX, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word, none of them can remove the last blank page.

I put the document (d.docx) [in the github directory](https://github.com/angmangm/test)

It's better not to use paid dlls, like aspose, etc.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have a hidden problem with your file. The last page is not blank, it contains continuation of the table. I selected the whole table and applied "all borders", after that the table appeared completely.

Now you will be able to choose the correct editing strategy for the document.

I guess you need to select last empty rows in the table and delete them. Any of Open XML, DocX, or "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word" can help you.

The VBA macro which removes last three rows in the table:

```
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'
'
  Selection.WholeStory
  Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
  Selection.MoveUp Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
  Selection.Rows.Delete
  Selection.MoveUp Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
  Selection.Rows.Delete
  Selection.MoveUp Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
  Selection.Rows.Delete
End Sub
```

It can be easily rewrite in c# with "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word".

Comment: I can't remove the last few rows with c# code, the runtime says "Unable to access separate rows in this collection because the table has vertically merged cells". It can only be deleted manually. Not sure how to delete the last rows with c# code.

Comment: It's a problem of neither c# nor the tool. If you will try to program it in Word's VBA, you will get the same result. But, I guess, solution can be found, probably, it will be complicate. Start to find it in VBA. In case of success you will be easily able to rewrite VBA code in c#.

Comment: Thank you very much, I translated your code into c# and it has the desired effect,

Word.Application wa = new Word.Application();
wa.Documents.Open("D:\d.docx");
wa.Visible = false;
if (wa.Documents.Count > 0)
{
        Word.Selection s = wa.Selection;
        s.WholeStory();
s.MoveRight(Unit: Word.WdUnits.wdCharacter, Count: 1);
 s.MoveUp(Unit: Word.WdUnits.wdLine, Count: 1);
 s.Rows.Delete();
 s.MoveUp(Unit: Word.WdUnits.wdLine, Count: 1);
 s.Rows.Delete();
 s.MoveUp(Unit: Word.WdUnits.wdLine, Count: 1);
 s.Rows.Delete();
}
else
{
 Console.WriteLine("no open file!");
}